# cross-reference auto-completion in TeXShop

Tags: cross-referencing, texshop, auto-completion

I use TeXShop 3.26 and have a root tex file and every chapter in a separate file. When I use the auto-completion feature for the ref command I only get the labels defined in the same file. Is it possible to get the labels of the whole document listed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems more like a feature request in TeXshop (software) than it is about (La)TeX.